# How to Partition a graph into possibly overlapping parts such that any vertex contained in a part has at least distance k from the Boundary?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

How to partition a graph into possibly overlapping parts such that any vertex is contained in a part at which it has at least distance k from the Boundary?

The problem arises in cases where the whole graph can not be loaded into a single machine
because there is not sufficient memory. So another requirement is that the partition has
somehow an equal number of vertices.

Are there any algorithms that try to minimize the common vertices between parts?

The use case here is this: You want to perform a query starting from an initial vertex that you know will require maximum k traversals. Having a part that contains all the vertices of this query results in zero
network utilization.
The problem thus is to reduce the memory overhead of such a partition.

Any books I should read?

I found this which looks promising:
http://grafia.cs.ucsb.edu/sedge/docs/sedge-sigmod12-slides.pdf

final edit: It is no coincidence that google decided to use a Hash partition.
Finding a good partition is difficult. I ll go with a hash partition as well and hope
that the data center has good network bandwidth.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Possibly a diagram explaining what you're after would help?

Comment: If you have initial partition, than it is enough to extend each partition with nodes on distance <= k from partition boundary. Problem is to get initial partition :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a breadth first search to get all the nodes that are only k distance away from the node in question, starting with the node itself. When you reach k away from the origin, you can end the search.

**Edit:**
Use a depth first search to assign a minimum distance from boundary property to each node. Once you have completed the depth first search, a simple iteration through the nodes should provide the partitions. For example, you can create a table that stores the minimum distance from boundary as the key and a vector of nodes as the value to represent the partition.

Comment: You partition the graph so as to do fast searches on maximum search distance k.